# Inkscape crashes when using pdflatex

Tags: 20.04, python, crash, inkscape

I started using Inkscape half a year ago and I was totally fine with it. A few days ago I wanted to add some inline LaTex (with pdflatex) to the project I was editing and when I click on apply the whole program crashes. I tried to go back to Inkscape 1.0.2 to see whether I can use that for editing but it still crashes.

I downloaded the 1.0.2 version from the [official website](https://inkscape.org/release/inkscape-1.0.2/gnulinux/appimage/dl/) as an AppImage. This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pdflatex.py", line 83, in <module>
    PdfLatex().run()
  File "/tmp/.mount_Inksca1ekPkB/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/base.py", line 140, in run
    self.save_raw(self.effect())
  File "/tmp/.mount_Inksca1ekPkB/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex/extensions.py", line 159, in effect
    for child in fragment:
  File "pdflatex.py", line 56, in generate
    with open(svg_file, 'r') as fhl:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/inktmp59sokxrc/output.svg'
```

This happens whenever I type "\". I can happily write "asd" and it works, but this is not how I want to use it.
As I am quite new to Ubuntu I have a hard time understanding what the problem is and what is the solution to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For more reproducible results I would recommend to use deb-based Inkscape.
You need to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive pstoedit inkscape
```

Then use its preinstalled LaTeX extension (Inkscape, *Extensions* → *Render* → *LaTeX*).

Note: if you want to get latest version of Inkscape 1.1 - then install packages from [official PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Einkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable?field.series_filter=focal) as follows

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

and use its built-in functionality via *Extensions* → *Render* → *Mathematics* → *LaTeX (pdflatex)*.

Comment: I reinstalled Inkscape based on your comment and now it works. Thanks! I think that I did not have all the dependencies installed previously and that caused the bug.

Comment: Same bug is present in Inkscape 1.2 PPA (Ubuntu 20.04). Shall I ask a new question and let you know here? @N0rbert